# How can I do the swipe?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, controls, swipe

I have a game made with unity, subway surfers like,  everything it's done BUT:
On the laptop I can use the arrow keys for left and right to move the player but on the phone I can't, no button, no tilt, no swipe, nothing.
I attached my script here, please help me with some controls, but to be the same value with left and right.
Thank you!

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Range(-2, 2)] public float value;
    public float Speed;
    Rigidbody rigid;
    private Transform player;
    private Vector3 desiredPosition;
    void Start()
    {
        rigid = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        transform.position = new Vector3(value, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
        rigid.velocity = (Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * Speed);
    }
    private void LateUpdate()
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Right"))
        {
            if (value == 2)
                return;
            value += 2;
        }
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Left"))
        {
            if (value == -2)
                return;
            value -= 2;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [swipe gestures on android in unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27712233/swipe-gestures-on-android-in-unity)

Comment: No, I can`t find answer in that topic.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that you need to find the position of the finger at the start using touch.position. Make sure that the touch is a touch. Then keep finding the position of the touch until it has traveled as far as you want it to. Then, call the function which moves the character. This unity documentation may help you as well with touch input.
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Touch.html