# Unity - Identify escape gesture

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input, mobile, escaping

This is a simplified version of my code.  The basic idea is to check for input. If the user presses escape the scene will change. If the user taps or clicks in an empty area a item will be placed in that area.

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape)) 
    {
        CheckEscape(); 
    } 
    else if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
    {
        PlaceItemOnTheBoard()
    }
}
```

This all works very well when I'm running the game on my laptop but when I run it on my phone (Pixel 4a), the escape is triggered by a swipe gesture.  When you perform this gesture it will place an item on the board and then triggers the CheckEscape() method.

Does anyone know a way to react to the escape gesture without placing an item on the board?

Comment: Any ideas anyone?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [swipe gestures on android in unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27712233/swipe-gestures-on-android-in-unity)

Comment: @DonTickner Unfortunately not.  The gesture in question is built into the android o/s.  You swipe left or right from the edge of the screen and it acts like a back-button.  This then sends a escape key to unity.  The problem I have is that mouse down/up are sent before escape.

Comment: If the pieces are placed and then escape is triggering correctly, then the Escape gesture is being captured correctly. The title of your question may not be accurate. It sounds to me that, when using Touch input, you're triggering actions at the beginning of an input, rather than the end of an input. In the question I linked, the examples cover how to detect the beginning and end of a touch input. You might need to implement handling to identify when a touch is completed, and then figuring out the single action needed.

Comment: I am actually detecting the beginning of the input too.  As I stated, I have displayed a simplified version of my code but I am using MouseButtonDown too to identify a press and release but I'm still getting both when you do an exit gesture.  I'm starting to think that the best way to deal with it is to undo any alterations if they occur a fraction of a second before hte exit gesture